# creating a series of buttons in a django html file

Tags: html, django, forms

Likely a pretty novice question, but I'm trying to come up with a simple way of setting up a list of html buttons in a list of variables:

```
{% for [object] in [list] %}
<tr>
    <td>
        <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="submit" name="[button name]" value="[?]">
        {% csrf_token %}
        </form>
    </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Question is: if I want the buttons to return different values based on the contents of the object at hand, how do I handle that?

Comment: you can use the {% if %} tag around your <input> markup.

Comment: sorry, I meant that I wanted to be able to return contents of the object, like its name, in the value for the button.

Comment: do you mean <input ... value="{{ obj.property }}">?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of overloading the submit button's value attribute, use a hidden field in the form to submit your values with the form.

`{% for [object] in [list] %}
<tr>
    <td>
        <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="my_parameter" value="{{object.property}}">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        {% csrf_token %}
        </form>
    </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}`

Comment: I'm an absolute novice here, but how do you go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what attributes your objects have, but you can access them like this:

```
<input type="submit" name="[button name]" value="{{ object.name }}">
```

Comment: Actually, so this gets me pretty close but the issue is that I want to be able to pass variable data to my views.py function, which is `if request.method == 'POST':
      if 'X' in request.POST:
         [do something]`

But if I stick the variable into the 'value' field, it messes with the button text; if I stick it in the 'name' field, I can't retrieve it in views.py.